# Saving NSManagedObject in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsmanagedobject, xcode7

Hello everyone (sorry for my bad english, I'm French),

I'm trying to put my `NSManagedObject` into `NSUserDefaults` to retrieve it with its relationships. Basically I used `NSCoding` and I had implemented the required method, but because it's `NSManaged` objects, the signature of the init method it's : init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?).

> The message is "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'shop' between objects in different contexts"

If I comment the line in Address : **`self.shop = shop`**, it's creating me my entity again and again..

This is my code :

To put the shop in `NSUserDefaults` :

```
let selectedShop = shopFetchedResultsController!.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row] as! Shop
let encodedShop = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(selectedShop)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(encodedShop, forKey: "currentShop")
```

And to retrieve it :

```
let encodedShop = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentShop") as! NSData
let currentShop = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedShop) as! Shop
```

Shop Entity :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Shop)
class Shop: NSManagedObject, NSCoding {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var phoneNumber: String
@NSManaged var address: Address
@NSManaged var products: NSSet

// MARK: - Managed Object Context Insertable
class var entityName: String {
    return "Shop"
}

struct Attributes {
    static let Name = "name"
    static let PhoneNumber = "phoneNumber"
    static let Address = "address"
    static let Products = "products"
}

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

convenience init(name:String, phoneNumber:String, address:Address,  products:NSSet) {
    self.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Shop", inManagedObjectContext: ManagedObjectContext.defaultContext)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ManagedObjectContext.defaultContext)
    self.name = name
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    self.address = address
    self.products = products

}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    let phoneNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("phoneNumber") as! String
    let address = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("address") as! Address
    let products = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("products") as! NSSet
    self.init(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, address: address,  products: products)
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encodeObject(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
    aCoder.encodeObject(address, forKey: "address")
    aCoder.encodeObject(products, forKey: "products")
}
```

Address Entity :

```
class Address: NSManagedObject, NSCoding {

@NSManaged var city: String
@NSManaged var country: String
@NSManaged var ext: String?
@NSManaged var number: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var postalCode: String
@NSManaged var street: String
@NSManaged var customers: NSSet
@NSManaged var shop: Shop

// MARK: - Managed Object Context Insertable
class var entityName: String {
    return "Address"
}

struct Attributes {
    static let City = "city"
    static let Country = "country"
    static let Ext = "ext"
    static let Number = "number"
    static let PostalCode = "postalCode"
    static let Street = "street"
    static let Customers = "customers"
    static let Shop = "shop"
}

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

convenience init(city:String, country:String, ext:String?, number:NSNumber?, postalCode:String, street:String, customers: NSSet, shop: Shop) {
    self.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Address.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: ManagedObjectContext.defaultContext)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ManagedObjectContext.defaultContext)
    self.city = city
    self.country = country
    self.ext = ext
    self.number = number
    self.postalCode = postalCode
    self.street = street
    self.customers = customers
   // self.shop = shop
}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let city = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("city") as! String
    let country = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("country") as! String
    let ext : String? = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("ext") as? String
    let number : NSNumber? = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("number") as? NSNumber
    let postalCode = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("postalCode") as! String
    let street = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("street") as! String
    let customers = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("customers") as! NSSet
    let shop = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("shop") as! Shop
    self.init(city: city, country: country, ext: ext, number: number, postalCode: postalCode, street: street, customers: customers, shop: shop)
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(city, forKey: "city")
    aCoder.encodeObject(country, forKey: "country")
    aCoder.encodeObject(ext, forKey: "ext")
    aCoder.encodeObject(number, forKey: "number")
    aCoder.encodeObject(postalCode, forKey: "postalCode")
    aCoder.encodeObject(street, forKey: "street")
    aCoder.encodeObject(customers, forKey: "customers")
    aCoder.encodeObject(shop, forKey: "shop")
}
```

I don't even know if it's the correct way to implement my entities..

For information, I use Swift2 and Xcode7.
If you need more details, just tell me, I can provide you other things !

Thank you a lot for your help ! Trust me, I spend 3 days on that without solutions...

Comment: I don't get any reason for you to save them again on an NSUserDefaults since it was already in your CoreData Stack with its relationships intact. Why don't you just try saving key fields for later use like your last CoreData session? I advice you to change your way of handling your data's since you're making it redundant. Not memory efficient

Comment: It's because I want to save the selected shop for later use. When I create an appointment, I want to associate it with the last selected shop. Basically, the user don't need to select a shop when he creates an appointment, I just get the selected shop from NSUserDefaults and associate it with the appointment. For you the solution is to save the index of the shop and retrieve the shop from this index ?

Comment: Yes.. you can save its id then retrieve it for later display or use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices ! And for your time. Have a nice day you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never do this. Core data objects are meant to be saved in DB only. However, you can use `NSUserDefaults` to save any key which you can later retrieve and use to fetch data from core data.

Comment: needlessly to say that a property list can only have specific types : NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSDate, NSData.

Comment: I take it for the answer although I have it in the comment below. Thank you !

Comment: @Abhinav how would you achieve this, save any key to later retrieve in a fetch?